# ArcGIS REST map server query doesn't return geometry as JSON?

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, map-service

I use Python code to query an ArcGIS map server. The [result link (as json)](https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Specialty/Soil_Survey_Map/MapServer/0/query?geometry=-9705493.14767,3587242.86394,-9685456.45466,3587242.86394,-9705493.14767,3561173.92735,-9685456.45466,3561173.92735&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=3857&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=mukey&returnGeometry=true&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnTrueCurves=true&f=json) only returns the Out Fields not the geometry. When I get the [result link as kmz](https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Specialty/Soil_Survey_Map/MapServer/0/query?geometry=-9705493.14767,3587242.86394,-9685456.45466,3587242.86394,-9705493.14767,3561173.92735,-9685456.45466,3561173.92735&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=3857&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=mukey&returnGeometry=true&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnTrueCurves=true&f=kmz) it seems to have the geometry, as I'm able to convert into the following layer:
[image]

Which appropriately looks like a subset of the service layer:
[image]

I've used the same query method successfully on other map servers (e.g. [tiger for US Census](https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/services/TIGERweb/tigerWMS_Current/MapServer/84/query?where=&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=-9705493.14767%2C3587242.86394%2C-9685456.45466%2C3587242.86394%2C-9705493.14767%2C3561173.92735%2C-9685456.45466%2C3561173.92735&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=3857&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=html)), any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just an FYI, mapserver isn't the same an an arcgis map service, which this is.

Comment: Can you supply your python code?

Comment: @Stella - This question is about the request (see result link as json) not how python formats/opens that request (urlopen from urllib). I get the same results w/ html (f=html) which is even easier to troubleshoot. I opted to omit it to keep the question simple and more general, but can add it if you think that will improve the question/answer-ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This service:

https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Specialty/Soil_Survey_Map/MapServer/0

Does not define any output fields of type `esriFieldTypeGeometry`, so it won't return geometry as JSON.

I suspect you shouldn't be getting it when requesting kmz either, but..